# ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130 ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)

Tags: oracle, http, plsql, oracle11g, acl

I need your help about ACL. Actually, I defined or create all procedures to reach the http. But always I am getting the same error as title. How can find where is the wrong?

And if you want you saw my script about this:

```
/*grant*/
grant execute on utl_http to "xxx";
grant execute on utl_smtp to "xxx";
grant execute on  utl_tcp to "xxx";

/*create acl*/
begin
   dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl (
      acl          => 'utl_http.xml',
      description  => 'http acl',
      principal    => 'xxx',
      is_grant     => TRUE,
       privilege    => 'connect',
       start_date   => null,
      end_date     => null);
    commit;
  end;
  /

/*Add privs*/
 begin
     dbms_network_acl_admin.add_privilege (
       acl         => 'utl_http.xml',
      principal   => 'xxx',
       is_grant    => true,
      privilege   => 'connect',
      position    => null,
       start_date  => null,
       end_date    => null);

    commit;
   end;
   /
 
    begin
     dbms_network_acl_admin.add_privilege (
       acl         => 'utl_http.xml',
      principal   => 'xxx',
       is_grant    => true,
      privilege   => 'resolve',
      position    => null,
       start_date  => null,
       end_date    => null);

    commit;
   end;
   /

/*Assign*/
BEGIN
 DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL (
  acl => 'utl_http.xml',
  host => '10.86.51.156',
  lower_port => NULL,
  upper_port => NULL);
END;
```

Db version: 11g
And also, I have 2 users. I tried both of them, one user is success about connection, this user has a DBA role, but another is not. But I guess DBA users is not necessary for ACL.

I used http code for testing - original code is very long. but this exp is giving the same error:

```
Declare
V_req utl_http.req;
V_resp utl_http.resp;
Begin
V_req:=utl_http.begin_request('http://10.86.51.156:10037');
V_resp:=utl_http.get_response(v_req);
Utl_http.end_response(v_resp);
End;
/
```

Comment: where is your http code?  there can be another underlying error. do you get the whole call stack from the http call?  Please post ALL the details.

Comment: I added the exp

Comment: where is the complete error/call stack? Try printing out the results of UTL_HTTP.GET_DETAILED_SQLERRM

Comment: can you login to the physical db server and run a curl command to http://10.86.51.156:10037?  What does it return?

Comment: Did you create an ACL entry in the database? Oracle 11 requires an explicit ACL whitelist for every outbound network call from PL/SQL.